# Bash output to variable not working?

Tags: bash, stdout

I am trying to get the output of a command set to a variable but when I run it with the Command substitution, the command returns a blank line

```
[user@host bin]$ ./MyAppRead 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[user@host bin]$ BALLS=$(./MyAppRead 4)
[user@host bin]$ echo $BALLS

[user@host bin]$
```

I am expecting BALLS to be set to "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" but it is blank?

-EDIT-

Changed to reflect the advice below. But still coming back blank

```
[user@host bin]$ ./MyAppRead 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[user@host bin]$ BALLS=$(./MyAppRead 4 2>&1)
[user@host bin]$ echo $BALLS

[user@host bin]$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segmentation fault  is a signal, and if you program gets it, it will be terminated and bash will print Segmentation fault message to shell (**not program**) stderr.

You can get this output by trapping segmentation fault signal with trap. Write this in file script.sh

```
/bin/bash
# script.sh
trap "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" 11
./MyAppRead 4
```

and then execute this

```
chmod +x script.sh
BALLS=$(./script.sh 2>&1)
echo $BALLS
```

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks! I actually decided instead to trigger on a successful message rather than a segfault and that worked on stdout just fine. But good to know for future use

Answer (score 6):

`$()` captures standard output, not standard error.  A segmentation fault error will go to standard error.

If you want both, you can capture both this way:

```
BALLS=$(./MyAppRead 4 2>&1)
```

Comment: Edited above to show the new command with your advice, but still the same blank output